# How to fix slow page changing speed to heavy routes with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-router

I have a React project and use React Router DOM v6 to manage all my routes.

I have a route that uses a fairly heavy component and, when switching to that heavy component, there is a 1+ second delay until the current page disappears and the new one shows up, since it's taking time to render that component.

Is there a way to change pages before trying to load the component and, perhaps, show a "loading" page while it's doing that?

[demo simulating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-d9qkfg?file=/src/App.js)

By "heavy route" I meant that it renders slowly whenever you change routes to it.

Comment: What is heavy on the page being navigated to? Without code it's quite difficult to provide any suggestions for improvement. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The heavy page cannot really be any more improved than what it's now, so I'm trying to improve the route switching instead. I tried to simulate a generic slow component, instead of recreating my case, because of that.

Comment: Can you share this heavy page component? It's still not clear what or why it is "heavy". Depending on what it's doing makes for different ways to improve/resolve its issues.

Comment: I can't share it, and reproducing it would be too complex. Also, even if it was solvable, I would still probably have this problem down the line anyway, so I really would like to find a way to get around it using React Router itself.

Comment: Ok, then I think you should look elsewhere. `react-router-dom` is a package that handles the use case of abstracting individual pages/routes for what is effectively a Single Page App. React has *some* performance enhancements to help memoize rendered results and values, i.e. the `memo` HOC and React hooks, but I think your "heavy" component likely needs a paradigm shift in its design/implementation. Think of something more along the lines of a design pattern, like virtualization, where you make what needs to be rendered at any given time only as much as it needs to be.

Comment: Heavy pages are a reality that we can't always avoid. I do think a loading / buffer functionality is something a router should be able to

Comment: I will try to use an HOC to switch to a loading component before going to the next page and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is implement [React.lazy()](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) to lazy load the page and then use [React.Suspense()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) to show a loading page while transitioning. Here is an example:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

// import MyPage from './pages/MyPage'
// instead of importing MyPage like above, use lazy, like below
const MyPage = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/MyPage'));

function App() {
    return (
        <Suspense
             fallback={<div><p>Loading...</p></div>}
        >
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/mypath' element={<MyPage} />
                // other route data                        
            </Routes>
        </Suspense>                
    )
}

export default App;
```

This is a very simple example. What this does is when you initially load your page, `MyPage` will not be loaded. Loading of the page will be deferred until it is needed. Once you go to `/mypath`, `MyPage` will then be loaded and the `Suspense` component will show the loading `<p>` tag. Of course this can be any element you want or even a component.

Alternatively, what you could do is, inside your big component, you could use `useState()` to create a simple boolean `isLoading` and `setIsLoading` state and set it to `true` initially. Then, render a loading component if `isLoading` is `true`. After your operation is completed, set `isLoading` to `false`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken and if the `MyPage component is just a big heavy React component then wouldn't OP still have the same performance issue once it's imported and getting rendered? Wouldn't they still have the navigation issue on subsequent navigations after it's been imported once? Lazy loading is a code splitting pattern, yes?

Comment: @DrewReese -- The performance would still be the same, but at least he'd get a loading message of some kind because of `<Suspense>`. My code example up above really wasn't to improve any performance. It was just to show him how he could get a loading sign.

Comment: The loading only happens once, if I'm not mistaken. I *could* be, not 100% certain. The component is only imported once, so I think the lazy part only occurs once, the first time. I think OP would still have the navigation issue later.

Comment: @DrewReese - I updated my answer to give him an alternative way of doing this using `useState()`

Comment: Right, the loading state makes much more sense, to get the component minimally rendering *something*, then switching to the heavy UI.

Comment: @DrewReese - When I originally read his question and he described it as a `heavy component`, my mind made me think the delay was because it was a large component in size and that was the delay. That's why I went with a lazy loading approach. After re-reading it though and thinking the issue in delay could be because of some kind of operation, I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the exact same thing, heavy UI, but there is room for ambiguity what "heavy" means with regards to performance, so I can't say anything for sure.

Comment: I meant heavy UI. I'm updating the OP to make that clear. What makes it slow is the rendering part, so I wouldn't be able to use state to tell exactly when it's done rendering. I think I could have a setTimeout that disables loading after, say, 500ms, just to make the page switching, but it does feel a bit hacky. Is this the best way we can go about this?

Comment: @Asghwor - I would try the `React.lazy()` approach as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: I thought React.lazy is just for slow imports. Will that make it switch to the loading screen every time I try to switch to that page and wait before the heavy full page render every time I try accessing it?

Comment: @Asghwor `React.lazy` is for code splitting of app components, and as I pointed out, once imported, the "heavy" component would still need to be mounted and rendered, so you'll still have that cost regardless.

Comment: @Asghwor - It's not so much the `React.lazy()` that should make this work the way you want it. It's wrapping your app in the `<Suspense>` tag. According to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense), `React.Suspense lets you specify the loading indicator in case some components in the tree below it are not yet ready to render`, which sounds exactly like what you want.

Comment: My current problem is the render phase being slow, though. Also, it would be nice if this solution was as generic as possible, so any page that's slow for any reason wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution to this? I'm currently having a similar issue where I'm loading 4-5 computational heavy components in a page and every time you click on the navigation to that page it takes 1 or 2 seconds to change. Feels very strange. The only solution I can think of is some sort of intersection observer implementation to render only whats visible.